# Join two tables to get matching records and unmatched records from Table 1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Scenario: I have 2 tables namely Coverage and Product

**Coverage Table:**
CId,CName,CType,CMessage,CDate,CoverageProductId

**Product Table:**
PId,CName,CType,CMessage,PDate,CoverageProductId

By using CoverageProductId i am relating 2 tables.

I need to get 3 columns CName,CMessage and CoverageProductId from both tables

Condition Below,

- Get 3 columns values from Product table if both table CoverageProductId matches.
- Get 3 columns values from Coverage table if both table CoverageProductId not matches.

My query is below in MS sql server

```
SELECT Distinct C.CoverageProductID
,C.CName
,C.CType
FROM Coverage C
INNER JOIN Product P
ON C.CoverageProductID!=P.CoverageProductID
UNION
SELECT Distinct P.CoverageProductID
,P.CName
,P.CType
FROM Coverage C
INNER JOIN Product P
ON C.CoverageProductID=P.CoverageProductID
```

But the result is not as expected and it returns duplicate values.

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected result. An sql fiddle would be better.

Comment: I think the logic of your conditions is screwy.  You want to retain records from `Coverage` which both match _and_ do not match in `Product`.  So this means you want the _entire_ `Coverage` table.  This table also contains, by definition, any records which match to `Product`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might do what you want:

```
select P.CoverageProductID, P.CName, P.CType
from Product P
where exists (select 1
              from coverage c
              where p.CoverageProductID = c.CoverageProductID)
union all
select C.CoverageProductID, C.CName, C.CType
from Coverage C
where not exists (select 1
                  from product p
                  where p.CoverageProductID = c.CoverageProductID);
```

It gets all rows from `Product` that match in `Coverage` and then all rows from `Coverage` that don't have a match in `Product`.

Comment: Oops, didn't notice your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried little better way for same query,

Below is my code,

```
SELECT 
ISNULL(P.CoverageProductID,C.CoverageProductID),
ISNULL(P.CType,C.CType)
ISNULL(P.CName,C.CName)
FROM   Coverage AS C
           LEFT OUTER JOIN
           Product AS P
           ON C.CoverageProductID = P.CoverageProductID
```