# compare two tables having different number of columns and return match and mismatching records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have to compare two tables and return match and mismatching records using primary key Emp Id
[image]

Lets say, something like this below should be in my result set.Again I should be getting both match and mismatch record.
If I use `EmpId=E2`,I should get match along with name and country mismatching values.
[image]
If I use `EmpId=E4`, city and Company mismatching.
[image]
Is ther any way we can do this? Please help me on this.

Ways i tried,

Used Full Join but it doesn’t return what I want.

```
Select * from Emplist A Full Join EmpInfo B on A.EmpId=B.EmpId where A.EmpId='E2'
```

I have referred this [article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2779/ways-to-compare-and-find-differences-for-sql-server-tables-and-data/) but does not suit my requirement.

**Note:I** dont want to mention columns in select statement as some times i would get 50+ columns in both table(Hard to write all column names in select statement)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Join two tables to get matching records and unmatched records from Table 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31737341/join-two-tables-to-get-matching-records-and-unmatched-records-from-table-1)

Comment: @thebrownkid this is not duplicate as i cant use Union with my scenario

Comment: Are you REALLY wanting the column names to change based on whether the record is a match or a mismatch for that column?    Because if so, then you're going to need a rather complicated dynamic sql solution.

Comment: @TabAlleman You are right. That's why i am seeking help from this forum. Do we have any other way identifying match and mismatching column?

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL Server's INTERSECT or EXCEPT.

» *EXCEPT returns distinct rows from the left input query that aren’t output by the right input query.*

» *INTERSECT returns distinct rows that are output by both the left and right input queries operator.*

You can view the online reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Here is an example you can run in SSMS:

Create table variables and insert data:

```
DECLARE @empList TABLE ( empId VARCHAR(2), [name] VARCHAR(20), city VARCHAR(20), company VARCHAR(3), country VARCHAR(4) );
DECLARE @empInfo TABLE ( empId VARCHAR(2), [name] VARCHAR(20), city VARCHAR(20), [language] VARCHAR(10), company VARCHAR(3), country VARCHAR(4) );

INSERT INTO @empList
( empId, [name], city, company, country )
VALUES
( 'E1', 'John', 'Newyork', 'CYT', 'Con1' )
, ( 'E2', 'Victor', 'London', 'KOP', 'Con2' )
, ( 'E3', 'David', 'BYJ', 'CKY', 'Con3' )
, ( 'E4', 'Neymor', 'Kiht', 'UIO', 'Con4' )
, ( 'E5', 'Justin', 'Paris', 'JHY', 'Con5' );

INSERT INTO @empInfo
( empId, [name], city, [language], company, country )
VALUES
( 'E1', 'John', 'Newyork', 'Eng', 'CYT', 'Con1' )
, ( 'E2', 'Marlya', 'London', 'French', 'KOP', 'Con9' )
, ( 'E3', 'David', 'BYJ', 'Eng', 'CKY', 'Con3' )
, ( 'E4', 'Neymor', 'LOV', 'Eng', 'UUM', 'Con4' )
, ( 'E5', 'Justin', 'Paris', 'Eng', 'JHY', 'Con5' );
```

INTERSECT results:

```
SELECT empId, [name], city, company, country FROM @empList
INTERSECT
SELECT empId, [name], city, company, country FROM @empInfo;

+-------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| empId |  name  |  city   | company | country |
+-------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| E1    | John   | Newyork | CYT     | Con1    |
| E3    | David  | BYJ     | CKY     | Con3    |
| E5    | Justin | Paris   | JHY     | Con5    |
+-------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
```

EXCEPT results:

```
SELECT empId, [name], city, company, country FROM @empList
EXCEPT
SELECT empId, [name], city, company, country FROM @empInfo;

+-------+--------+--------+---------+---------+
| empId |  name  |  city  | company | country |
+-------+--------+--------+---------+---------+
| E2    | Victor | London | KOP     | Con2    |
| E4    | Neymor | Kiht   | UIO     | Con4    |
+-------+--------+--------+---------+---------+
```

Return single resultset:

```
SELECT * FROM (

    SELECT 'matched' [state], empId, [name], city, company, country FROM @empList
    INTERSECT
    SELECT 'matched' [state], empId, [name], city, company, country FROM @empInfo

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'mismatched' [state], empId, [name], city, company, country FROM @empList
    EXCEPT
    SELECT 'mismatched' [state], empId, [name], city, company, country FROM @empInfo

) AS singleResultset;
```

Returns

```
+------------+-------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
|   state    | empId |  name  |  city   | company | country |
+------------+-------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| matched    | E1    | John   | Newyork | CYT     | Con1    |
| matched    | E3    | David  | BYJ     | CKY     | Con3    |
| matched    | E5    | Justin | Paris   | JHY     | Con5    |
| mismatched | E2    | Victor | London  | KOP     | Con2    |
| mismatched | E4    | Neymor | Kiht    | UIO     | Con4    |
+------------+-------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
```

The caveat here is that the column names need to match ( they can be aliased ) which for the most part they do in your example. Notice that I left out the "language" column from @empInfo SELECT.

Comment: Thanks.But i need both macth and mismatch columns in single resultset. btw i dont want to mention columns in select statement as some times i would get 50+ columns(i hate to mention all column names in select statement)

Comment: Yeah, the columns can be a bear, but you can alias them. I've updated my sample to include return all results as a single resultset.

Comment: Sorry I am newbie, how to do that?

Comment: Check out my updated example to see the single resultset.

As for aliasing, its simple:  SELECT MyColumn AS MyNewColumnName;

Comment: Thanks,but still is there any way we can do without mentioning column names? think how could i mention 50+ columns, that;s really a painful task.

Comment: Also, if there is a column missing from a table being compared--in your case empList is missing the "language" column from empInfo, you can add it by using a NULL or empty string and aliasing that.

For example:
SELECT NULL AS MyNullValue, '' AS MyEmpyString, … **HOWEVER** this will cause *all* records to mismatch as is a fictitious column.

Comment: @J_Coder I Don't believe so. I don't see any way getting around that no matter what method you use if the columns between the two sources do not match.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176438/discussion-between-j-coder-and-critical-error).

Comment: You can use this snippet of code to select a list of column names that can be copied and pasted into your selects. It'll save some time: SELECT STUFF(
 ( SELECT ', ' + [name] AS "text()" FROM sys.columns WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID( {your_table_name_here}) FOR XML PATH( '' ) )
 , 1
 , 2
 , ''
) AS ColumnList

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a query for OUTER EXCLUDING JOIN. OUTER EXCLUDING JOIN only returns values that are not equal across two tables, however as far as I know you cannot simply replace the phrase "INNER JOIN" with "OUTER EXCLUSIVE JOIN"

The process for that would be to write two queries, a FULL JOIN - which will return everything - and an INNER JOIN which will only return identical columns. From this, write a query which merges the FULL JOIN where it does not have the values from INNER JOIN. The results from this query will only be those where the rows from the two tables are not alike.

I would reference [this thread](https://community.qlik.com/thread/153169) and this [Code Project post](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins) for greater detail.